# Try Catch not working in v2.0, though working in 4.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When I put this snippet into powershell v2.0 on one of my machines

```
try{
    $test = 1/0
    write-host "not terminating"
}
Catch{
    write-host "caught"
}
write-host "continuing"
```

the error terminates the script and doesn't catch it and doesn't continue. I get the cannot divide by zero error.

```
Cannot divide by zero exception message
```

But in my v4.0 i get this output

```
caught
continuing
```

when I put that into my v4.0 powershell it catches the terminating error and it continues. Whats the deal, is this a v2.0 specific issue? How do I get the script to continue in powershell v2.0 and catch the error?

Comment: I get the duplicate and it explains the 2.0 behavior but how does it address what is happening with v4? I would think they should be the same based on what I just read in the other post.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` in your try block.  This will turn all errors in to terminating errors.  There might be a problem between v2 and v4 of powershell, where v4 defines an error as terminating, but v2 does not.  Try/catch statements only work on terminating errors.

If that doesnt work, try writing something like:

```
try {
  $test = 1/0

  if($?) {
     write-host "not terminating"
  }

  else {
      $errors[0].Exception
  }
}
```

$? is an automatic variable that stores information whether the last operation completed successfully or not.

Comment: I know it's a terminating error as the script terminates and the "not terminating" doesn't get output, as if it wasn't terminating it should output both "not terminating" and "continuing". Though i will test this regardless to see if anything changed. EDIT: Yeah, the results were still the same, it's really bothering me as microsoft has this documented to behave differently than it is. Or maybe I'm not understanding error handling correctly?

Comment: I tested the block of code, the script just terminated and then output the usual cannot divide by zero error

Comment: @gzimmers I actually got it to work based on what the other guy said.  Just change it to `$test = 0   $test2 = 1/$test`